# Почему DataFrame.shift не работает с ячейкой?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Почему смещение .shift отказывается работать?

```
df['atras'].shift(df['random'])
```

То есть, оно не хочет взаимодействовать с `df['random']` и выдает ошибку.

Как можно исправить?

```
df['random'] = np.random.randint(-2, 2, size = len(df))
df['atras2'] = df['atras'].shift(df['random'])
```

Пример:

```
Date        atras   random  atras2
20160901    471     1           
20160901    462     -1      431     
20160901    431     2       471 
20160901    483     0       483 
20160901    463     1       483
```

Ошибка:

```
c:\users\ii\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in shift(self, periods, freq, axis, fill_value)
   4544     def shift(self, periods=1, freq=None, axis=0, fill_value=None) -> "Series":
   4545         return super().shift(
-> 4546             periods=periods, freq=freq, axis=axis, fill_value=fill_value
   4547         )
   4548 

c:\users\ii\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in shift(self, periods, freq, axis, fill_value)
   9429         2020-01-08    45    48    52
   9430         """
-> 9431         if periods == 0:
   9432             return self.copy()
   9433 

c:\users\ii\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1441     def __nonzero__(self):
   1442         raise ValueError(
-> 1443             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1444             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1445         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Включите в вопрос полный стек ошибки. И что вы хотите получить данной командой: `df['atras'].shift(df['random'])` ??

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод [Series.shift(periods=1, freq=None, axis=0, fill_value=None)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) ожидает в качестве параметра `periods` целое **скалярное** значение.

Т.е. Pandas не поддерживает динамическое смещение с разным шагом смещения. Шаг смещения должен быть один и должен быть задан как целое скалярное значение.

---

**UPD:** Вариант векторизированного решения:

```
idx = np.arange(len(df)) - df["random"]
# заменяем индексы выходящие за правую границу на `-1`
idx[idx >= len(df)] = -1

df["res"] = np.where(idx >= 0, df["atras"].to_numpy()[idx], np.nan)
```

результат:

```
In [123]: df
Out[123]:
       Date  atras  random  atras2    res
0  20160901    471       1     NaN    NaN
1  20160901    462      -1   431.0  431.0
2  20160901    431       2   471.0  471.0
3  20160901    483       0   483.0  483.0
4  20160901    463       1   483.0  483.0
```

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе [mcve] и результат который вы хотите получить?

Comment: @kocwab, векторизированным способом это сделать нельзя, придется делать это в цикле